# gcc warning flag when variable scope can be reduced in C

Tags: c, gcc, scope, static-code-analysis

As part of "good practice" when writing C source code, I'm trying to reduce variable scopes as much as possible.

Some external tools such as `cppcheck` can help, and provide warnings when a scope variable is larger than it needs to be.

I haven't found an equivalent warning flag for `gcc`, but the list of available flags is notoriously large and evolving, so it's difficult to grasp them all. I may just be missing it.

Does such a flag exist ?

Comment: Compiler is not a static analyzer. While gcc and clang already have very good warnings, their main target here is most common mistakes, where it helps a lot to get a warning as early as possible (i.e. during normal compilation). However there are a lot of cases compiler doesn't check, because it will add significant compilation time, is too difficult to implement with current compiler logic (e.g. unreachable code warnings were a thing, but now gone), or it takes quite an effort to do this checks, instead of improving other things. Use different analyzers regularly.

Comment: Sure. My line or reasoning was that gcc already has `-Wshadow`, which is about overlapping scope. So it already properly analyse variables' scopes. That's certainly no proof that an option to optimize variable scope exist, but worth a check.

Comment: Well compiler have to know about overshadowing to use correct variable, so this warning is very cheap both it implementation effort and execution time. Checking for scope reduction is completely different task. So short answer is - none I'm aware of, and I don't think you'll find it in any compiler. You can check `clang --analyze`, but it is a separate pass aside from compilation, and I don't think it checks for scopes either.

Comment: I am not sure that minimizing variable scope is making the code more readable. Your approach would suggest having much more blocks, and sometimes that does not improve readability. However, you could code a GCC plugin (perhaps using [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)...) for such a purpose.

Comment: The initial idea of this question is to take advantage of _existing_ scopes, to reduce scope of a variable when it fits entirely into a lower, more restricted, scope.

Creating additional scopes would be a separate question.

Thanks for the link on MELT